# how to use java agent to handle applet events

Tags: java, applet, instrumentation, agent, endorsed

I'm trying to handle events in Java forms I don't have the source for.
until now I used the endorsed folder to replace `java.applet.Applet` with my own inherited implemention.
but endorsed is disabled in Java 9.

now I'm looking for a new solution, and I'm trying to use Java Agent with instrumentation to achieve the same thing.
but when I add a class and use it I also need to provide all of the Applet classes I import in a ClassLoader.
and the jars i need to import are on a web server i don't know the URL to, and I don't want to add them manually (in the endorsed solution i didn't need to do it)

is there another way to do it? or am I missing something?

Comment: Is it relevant to de-compile the code and use the de-compiled source code in you own code?

Comment: @DavidRabinowitz is right - decompile the binary

Comment: the problem is that jars are on a remote server and the user opens the applet via web browser